# Beats music: "Developer Inactive" error message when making request to /me endpoint

Tags: beatsmusic

I keep getting a developer inactive message when attempting to request the user ID at the /me endpoint on the beats music API. However, the API seems to be returning correct JSON data when making requests to any other endpoint. Any ideas? Here's an image of my request in the playground: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w315cpkfos6z7ni/developerinactive.png

Answer (score 0):

This is working on our end. There are a few things that could be happening:
- We can check your limits on our end.
- You may want to refresh your token. 
- We'd also like to check your Beats Music account (trial, paid, etc)